# Why is the sub-header font in the stack exchange app only displaying the top half of header titles in iOS?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, ios-app, rendering

I haven't updated my iOS Stack Exchange app in a long time, and suddenly I am noticing differences or glitches in how it works or displays/renders itself.

When posting a question, before typing anything into the topic box, the words "Question Title" appear, but the bottom half of the letters are chopped off. Why is this? I wonder if anyone else has this font rendering glitch.

I'm running iOS 12.3.1. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Pic of Stack exchange iOS GUI graphics text size rendering bug]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 12.3.1 (Build 16F203)

Comment: Is the app even maintained anymore? Why not use the responsive view on your browser, works just as fine.

Comment: @Luuklag It’s still on the App Store but I don’t see any updates. And I don’t want to use the browser because I like the app! I also don’t like logging in and out on a browser all the time and would rather not stay logged in on a browser permanently, as the browser is one of the biggest attack vectors.